# Use MyBatis cache to load entire table and query

Tags: caching, mybatis

This is what is want to achieve using MyBatis cache(or combining with ehCache/others):
-load the entire result set for an aggregate query into cache
-ability to query this result set and apply sql based filter(between start and end dates)

I searched around the web but could not find an answer to this. 
Please help. 
Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache has search [API](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/search), you can load entries to cache and afterwords search it based on whatever criteria you like, including dates.
Of course this means implementing caching mechanism yourself, maybe by extending [EhcacheCache](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Caches) or since you're using Spring maybe extending [AbstractCacheManager or EhCacheCacheManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) could be an option.
But there should be performance [conciderations](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/search#implementation-and-performance), since cache is mean not for querying, but for caching, especially standalone Ehcache version.